# Why are non-trivial powers called perfect powers?

Tags: terminology, definition, perfect-numbers, perfect-powers

Let *number* mean *positive integer*.

What makes a number [perfect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number) is quite intricate:

> A perfect number is a number that is equal to the sum of its proper divisors.

What makes a number a [power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation) is also quite intricate:

> A number $N$ is a power (number) if there exist numbers $n, k$ such that $N=n^k$.

But what makes a number a [perfect power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_power) is quite boring:

> A power number $N=n^k$ is perfect if $n,k > 1$.

I wonder why so much ado is made when calling a (non-trivial) power "a *perfect* power" ("Ah, $16$ is a *perfect* power!"), and not just "a power".

Comment: I think "perfect" here carries connotations of "lucky". The set of perfect powers has density zero in the naturals, but efficient algorithms exist for testing whether a number is one, and if a number turns out to be a perfect power, working with that number is much simplified.

Comment: IMHO, perfect power or perfect square or the like is rather used as an emphasis: Surely $7$ is the quare of $\sqrt 7$, hence is "a square" - but it is not a *perfect* square. Note that this is language-specific, e.g. in German  perfect square is simply a "Quadratzahl" ("square number"), and the WP artcile "perfect power" links to a Danish article "Potestal" ("power number")

Comment: Definitions are just definitions, and also some people use "powers" and "perfect powers" as synonymous. Anyway, there is no risk of confusion. Another story would be asking about, e.g., the meaning of "completeness" in different, but strictly related, mathematical subjects..

Comment: I believe the origins of the term "perfect number" is entirely coincidental to the terminology of "perfect power".  Just as we need a concept of "whole number" to distinguish between integers that are a integer multiples of integers as opposed to real numbers that are real number multiples of reals (i.e. *all* reals) we need terminology to determine integer powers of integer bases as opposed to real bases and real powers.

Comment: I also don't think "perfect power" is all that common.  I only hear it used when it needs to be specified that the mean a power of a whole number.  If example "if $x^n = b$, an integer then $x$ is rational iff $b$ is a perfect $n$ power"  Well obvious if $b$ is *always* an $n$ power of *something*...  we need something to indicate we mean an $n$ power of an *integer*.  In fact, that's pretty much the only time I've ever heard the term.